# How to add conditional class into PHP regex filter

Tags: php, regex

The code below detects URL's in a body of text and wraps them in  tags.

```
 function link_it($text)  
    {

        $text= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)((ht|f)tp(s)?:\/\/[\w]+[^ \,\"\n\r\t<]*)/is", "$1$2<a href=\"$3\" >$3</a>", $text);  
        $text= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)((www|ftp|m)\.[^ \,\"\t\n\r<]*)/is", "$1$2<a href=\"http://$3\" >$3</a>", $text);  
        $text= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([a-z0-9&\-_\.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+)+)/i", "$1<a href=\"mailto:$2@$3\">$2@$3</a>", $text);  
        return($text);  
    }
```

I would like it so that if a user types a url (detected via the function above) with a specific domain of (flickr|youtube|vimeo) etc the function adds the class "embed to the  tag template, otherwise it leaves it classless.

e.g.

'this is the website www.google.com' would return:

```
this is the website <a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>
```

but 'this is the website www.flickr.com' would return

```
this is the website <a href="http://www.flickr.com" class="embed">http://www.flickr.com</a>
```

How would I go about adding this into the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for this.  In your callback function, match the URL against some set of URLs that should have the `embed` class, and if it matches, include the `class` attribute definition, otherwise don't.

Comment: It works beautifully! Thank you.  Combined with parse_url it makes for a nice and elegant solution.  Great answer and a little embarrassed that I wasn't aware of that function!